# Is it possible to call an AMPScript function upon link click?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to do something like:

```
<a href="%%=UpdateDataExtension("", "", "", "")=%%">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly.  AMPScript is server-side, not client-side.

Assuming you want to store more information that what's recorded in the `_Click` [System Data View](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/), you can set up a [Landing Page](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/landing_pages/) or [Microsite Page](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/) to read the information from the link's URL and then use AMPScript or SSJS to record the data in the Data Extension.

In the email:

```
%%[

var @lpURL
set @lpURL = "https://linktolandingpage.com"

]%%

<a href="%%=redirectto(@lpURL)=%%" alias="linkAlias">link text</a>
```

The [redirectto()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/#RedirectTo) function ensures that subscriber context info (and Web Analytics Connector info, if configured) is passed to the target page.

Then on the target page:

```
%%[

var @emailAddr = AttributeValue("emailAddr")
// do your DE update here
redirect("http://finaltargetpage.com")

]%%
```

The subscriber context consists of any [Personalization Strings](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/) from the send and any [Profile Attributes](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/) from the List or columns from the Data Extension used for the send.